# Update image without flickering ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, flicker

Im writing a web site which has a page that must show an image. This image is created by an HttpHandler using querystring commands, how can I make this works without any kind of flickering?

Thanks in advance, if you need some code Im happy to share it!

Comment: What do you mean by "flickering"? Is the image update per AJAX and there should be a smooth transition to the new image or is the complete page reloaded?

Comment: Yes exactly, there is a trasition moment that I want to remove, for a moment the image is empty and then it is filled with the new one. I put everything inside an UpdatePanel, image and the others controls that cause autopostback but as I sadi before there's not a smooth transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code for a project, where I had a similar problem. Maybe this can help solve your issue.

```
 (function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  }
})(jQuery)
```

After preloading the images, the transition was very smooth.

p.s. I don't remember where I got this, so I can't give credit. Sorry.

Comment: The problem is that my images are generated by an httphandler listening on my page, so every time users move one of the controls inside the page this httphandler generate a new image to display. I should intercept the right moment when new image is ready and do something there to avoid flicker ...

Answer (score 3):

You could use 2 UpdatePanels and switch them after each "reload":

> Load Frame1 into Panel1 and hide Panel2 at Postback/Pageload
>   Load Frame2 into Panel2 per AJAX and after the Image is loaded show Panel2 and hide Panel1
>   Load Frame3 into Panel1 per AJAX and after the Image is loaded show Panel1 and hide Panel2
>   aso....

You then could even make a smooth fading from Panel1->Panel2 using JS (see [HERE](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation) or easier with jQuery [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)).

Comment: Ok, I'll try later. Can you please give me more info about smooth fadind js code?