# AJAX Prevent Images from being loaded over and over?

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, image

So I have a simple AJAX request (not JQuery):

```
function ajaxfunction(){
var ajaxRequest;
try{
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            alert("Your browser sucks"); //error
            return false;
        }
    }
}

ajaxRequest.open("GET", 'pull.php?ms='+new Date().getTime(), true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);  
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
```

}

And I want the request to also pull pictures. Since the request is dynamic (the images shown will change) I do the request over and over. This, however, makes the images flicker. I tried `<img src="foobar.jpg" style="visibility:none;" onLoad="this.style.visibility='visible';" />` but that doesn't really help. If anybody knows of any fix, thank you in advance. :D

Comment: using `Your browser sucks` as a notice that the browser doesn't support XMLHttpRequest is not best practice lol, not to mention if javascript is not enabled the alert() wont happen anyway, think linx..

Comment: Just noticed that you are not checking the status code of the ajax response in the code provided.  You might want to consider checking for a status code of 200 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of pulling then entire `<img>` tag in the ajax response just get the image name and properties to change the targeted image `src`, `height`, `width`, etc... properties to use the new image.

Comment: I like that thinking! Worth a try anyways :)

Comment: It can't work in my instance; I'm making a chatroom, and this is the request for who is online. The quantity of the images AND the images themselves can change. I need to request an ENTIRELY new image, causing the other images to flicker. Flickering isn't really a problem though.

Comment: Maybe you should put a snippet of the html returned in the response in the question so we have something to work with. Also, are all of the images the same size?  Just found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648517/update-image-without-flickering-asp-net-c It's for .NET, but there are some techniques that may help you out

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if including the image height and width in the style attribute of the img tag would help since it takes a split second for the browser to start downloading the image and get the actual image height and width.